# Visual Studio 2019 standard library generates warnings

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I want to make project with maximal warning level and treat warnings as errors.

There is my `CmakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.17.0 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /Wall /WX /EHcs")

project(pedantic)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable (pedantic main.cpp)
```

There is my `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "abc";
    std::cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

I generate the solution using the following command:

```
cmake ../ -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

The output is:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Programming/Progz/C++/pedantic/build_x64_VS2019
```

After that I build this program:

```
cmake --build . --config Release
```

And I get a lot of warnings:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\ostream(118): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\ostream(118): warning C4710: 'void __cdecl std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Osfx(void) __ptr64': function not inlined [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\ostream(103): warning C4710: 'class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __ptr64 __cdecl std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::flush(void) __ptr64': function not inlined [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\buil
d_x64_VS2019\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\exception(316): warning C4710: '__cdecl std::bad_array_new_length::bad_array_new_length(void) __ptr64': function not inlined [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xmemory(131): warning C4710: 'void __cdecl std::_Throw_bad_array_new_length(void)': function not inlined [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xmemory(229): warning C4711: function 'void * __ptr64 __cdecl std::_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned<struct std::_Default_allocate_traits>(unsigned __int64)' selected for automatic inline expansion [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019
\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xmemory(229): warning C4711: function 'void * __ptr64 __cdecl std::_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned<struct std::_Default_allocate_traits>(unsigned __int64)' selected for automatic inline expansion [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019
\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstring(511): warning C4710: 'int __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputc(char) __ptr64': function not inlined [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstring(519): warning C4710: '__int64 __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const * __ptr64,__int64) __ptr64': function not inlined [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstring(523): warning C4710: 'int __cdecl std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputc(char) __ptr64': function not inlined [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstring(531): warning C4710: 'void __cdecl std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool) __ptr64': function not inlined [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstring(534): warning C4710: 'void __cdecl std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool) __ptr64': function not inlined [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstring(4475): warning C4710: 'void __cdecl std::_Xlen_string(void)': function not inlined [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xmemory(229): warning C4711: function 'void * __ptr64 __cdecl std::_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned<struct std::_Default_allocate_traits>(unsigned __int64)' selected for automatic inline expansion [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019
\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xmemory(229): warning C4711: function 'void * __ptr64 __cdecl std::_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned<struct std::_Default_allocate_traits>(unsigned __int64)' selected for automatic inline expansion [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019
\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstring(3230): warning C4710: 'class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > & __ptr64 __cdecl std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::assign(char const * __ptr64 c
onst,unsigned __int64) __ptr64': function not inlined [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xmemory(229): warning C4711: function 'void * __ptr64 __cdecl std::_Allocate_manually_vector_aligned<struct std::_Default_allocate_traits>(unsigned __int64)' selected for automatic inline expansion [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019
\pedantic.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\xstring(4947): warning C4711: function 'class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __ptr64 __cdecl std::operator<<<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_tr
aits<char> > & __ptr64,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const & __ptr64)' selected for automatic inline expansion [D:\Programming\Progz\C++\pedantic\build_x64_VS2019\pedantic.vcxproj]
```

All of them comes from MSVS native standard library. I believe this compiler behavior is totally unacceptable.

How can I get rid of these warnings without changing warning level?

Comment: _"and treat [all] warnings as errors."_ - this is inadvisable: lots of warnings exist in cases where the compiler simply can't prove something is correct or safe due to limitations of the language (or just fundamental computer science).

Comment: Treat them as external headers? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/customized-warning-levels-and-code-analysis-for-external-headers/

Comment: @Dai , Even if it is inadvisable, I got 17 (seventeen, Carl!!!) unwanted warnings in a hello-world program. I will drown in such rubbish warnings and miss important ones.

Comment: Any reason to be using `cmake` rather than putting together a Visual Studio project and then using `MSBuild`?  I do it that way and am not experiencing any problems like this.  I agree that a warning-free build is the thing to shoot for.

Comment: @ChrisMM , yes, cmake treats them as external headers. `/external:W0` parameter partially solved the issue: inside the Visual Studio warnings disappeared. But console build still generates warnings.

Comment: *pedantic* means something else in MSVC.  Practical for GCC, but MSVC gets truly pedantic and you get warnings from missed optimization opportunities and code generation choices that don't match expectations.  /W3 is the default, /W4 is okay, you don't want /Wall.

Comment: @PaulSanders , The reason is making cross-platform application and having a single project generator for different compilers.

Comment: @HansPassant , Okay, /W4 does not generate warnings. Is any solution to see warnings from missed optimization opportunities (because the main reason to use C++ is performance) only from my code?

Comment: @MichaelLukin _The reason is_ OK, so, how do you plan to debug on, specifically, Windows?  Without a VS project file, you will be struggling.  The same will probably apply to the other platforms you want to support.  I personally would not want to give up the awesome facilities of a modern IDE.

Comment: @PaulSanders , the command `cmake ../ -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` generates a solution file that can be opened in MSVS. So I use all the advantages of using modern IDEs.
Also CmakeLists.txt can be opened as a project in powerful Clion IDE.

Comment: Ah, cool features

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT Yes, it works. As far as I understand, this is the maximum that can be done with warnings.

Comment: Glad to know your problem has been solved! You could click '✔' to accept it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVC enables a ton of 'informational' warnings that are 'off-by-default' when you use `/Wall`. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/cpp/preprocessor/compiler-warnings-that-are-off-by-default).

If you want to make use of 'maximal warnings' with MSVC, then you need to suppress a bunch of them selectively. For my GitHub projects, I use this but have a bunch of suppressions typically managed in a header using a `#pragma`.

```
// Off by default warnings
#pragma warning(disable : 4619 4616 4061 4265 4365 4571 4623 4625 4626 4628 4668 4710 4711 4746 4774 4820 4987 5026 5027 5031 5032 5039 5045 5219 5246 5264 26812)
// C4619/4616 #pragma warning warnings
// C4061 enumerator 'X' in switch of enum 'X' is not explicitly handled by a case label
// C4265 class has virtual functions, but destructor is not virtual
// C4365 signed/unsigned mismatch
// C4571 behavior change
// C4623 default constructor was implicitly defined as deleted
// C4625 copy constructor was implicitly defined as deleted
// C4626 assignment operator was implicitly defined as deleted
// C4628 digraphs not supported
// C4668 not defined as a preprocessor macro
// C4710 function not inlined
// C4711 selected for automatic inline expansion
// C4746 volatile access of '<expression>' is subject to /volatile:<iso|ms> setting
// C4774 format string expected in argument 3 is not a string literal
// C4820 padding added after data member
// C4987 nonstandard extension used
// C5026 move constructor was implicitly defined as deleted
// C5027 move assignment operator was implicitly defined as deleted
// C5031/5032 push/pop mismatches in windows headers
// C5039 pointer or reference to potentially throwing function passed to extern C function under - EHc
// C5045 Spectre mitigation warning
// C5219 implicit conversion from 'int' to 'float', possible loss of data
// C5246 the initialization of a subobject should be wrapped in braces
// C5264 'const' variable is not used
// 26812: The enum type 'x' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over 'enum' (Enum.3).
```

Alternatively, you'll have to suppress a lot of stuff via the command-line:

```
if( CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC" )
    set(DisableWarnings "/wd4365" "/wd4514" "/wd4625" "/wd4626" "/wd4627" "/wd4710" "/wd4820" "/wd5026" "/wd5027" "/wd5039" "/wd5045")
    if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_GREATER_EQUAL 19.34)
        list(APPEND DisableWarnings "/wd5262" "/wd5264")
    endif()
    target_compile_options(yourtarget PRIVATE ${DisableWarnings})
```

> For the best conformance out of MSVC, use `/permissive- /Zc:__cplusplus /Zc:inline /Zc:preprocessor` as well.

> One more note, if you make `3.20` your minimum supported CMake, then you can count on there not being any `/W3` or `/GR` in the default CL flags. That way, you can use **target_compile_options** instead of playing games with `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.  `/EHsc` is always there for MSVC-like.